# The Bag of Marbles Phenomena

Tags: python, variables, math

QUESTION:

I have a bag of marbles with a total volume of 33. There are two kinds of marbles in my bag. Blue marbles that have a volume of 3 and red marbles that have a volume of 6. If I have 8 marbles in the bag, how many blue and red marbles do I have?

I have been trying to create a code that tells me how many red and blue marbles there are but I cant seem to solve this. Any Ideas?

For this specific problem there should be 5 Blue and 3 Red.

Comment: Also I am using Python, thnx!

Comment: What is your exact question? You have two simple linear equations with two unknowns. What did you try? Do you want to use numpy, scipy, sympy, z3py, ....  How general do you want your implementation to be?

Comment: Questions asking for homework help must include a summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem, and a description of the difficulty you are having solving it. Please read [How to ask homework questions](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822) and [edit] your post.

Comment: This isn't homework its for a part of my research. I will put what I have in a few hours I am not home atm. As general as possible, I just need to see a simple example of how the code can solve this. The size of the marbles is constant. The volume of the bag is achieved by adding the size of the marbles together. And we know how many marbles there are everytime. Just need to have it tell me the exact amount of Blue vs Red.

Comment: there is only 1 unknown being how many red and blue marbles there are.

Comment: Well, that's not worded correctly.  There is only 1 unknown, because red and blue are not independent.  The unknown can EITHER be "number of red" or "number of blue".

Comment: And this is trivial algebra, right?  6R + 3(8-R) = 33, so 6R + 24 - 3R = 33, so 3R = 9, and there are 3 reds and thus 5 blues.  Python is not really required.  ;)

Answer (score 1):

You could use sympy to find formulas for this type of equations (and even much more complicated ones). Just write down all the equations and call `solve`.

Here is an example.

```py
from sympy import var, Eq, solve

var('total_volume volume_blue volume_red num_marbles num_blue num_red')
sol = solve([Eq(num_blue + num_red, num_marbles),
             Eq(num_blue * volume_blue + num_red * volume_red, total_volume)],
            [num_blue, num_red])
values = {total_volume: 33, volume_blue: 3, volume_red: 6, num_marbles: 8}
print(f'Formula for num_blue: {sol[num_blue]} ({sol[num_blue].subs(values)} for the given values)')
print(f'Formula for num_red: {sol[num_red]} ({sol[num_red].subs(values)} for the given values)')
```

Output:

```py
Formula for num_blue: (-num_marbles*volume_red + total_volume)/(volume_blue - volume_red)
   (5 for the given values)
Formula for num_red: (num_marbles*volume_blue - total_volume)/(volume_blue - volume_red)
   (3 for the given values)
```

Comment: Could you explain the formula it is using more clearly? I see that it is working which is great but when I try to make the formula: (-num_marbles*volume_red + total_volume)/(volume_blue - volume_red) for the num_blue I get 27 not 5...

Comment: `(-num_marbles*volume_red + total_volume)/(volume_blue - volume_red) = (-8*6 + 33)/(3 - 6) = (-48 + 33)/(-3) = (-15)/(-3)`.  Note that the formula doesn't know the values beforehand, and doesn't know which expressions will be negative. If you know that `volume_red` will be the largest, you would write `(num_marbles*volume_red - total_volume)/(volume_red - volume_blue)`, but sympy doesn't care

Answer (score 0):

```
s_3 = 63333663
s_6 = 66333663

s_3_list = [int(x) for x in str(s_3)]
s_6_list = [int(x) for x in str(s_6)]
sct_3_chng = sum(s_3_list)
sct_6_chng = sum(s_6_list)
print("INPUT QUADRANT\n")
print("SCT 3 CHANGE: ",sct_3_chng)
print("SCT 6 CHANGE: ",sct_6_chng)

time = 0
for x in str(s_3):
    time = time + 1
print("TIME: ",time)



#NEXT is retrieving the quantity of 3's and 6's in each sector.

s_3_q3 = (time * 6 - sct_3_chng)/(6 - 3)
s_3_q6 = (time - s_3_q3)
print("SECT 3 THREES: ",s_3_q3)
print("SECT 3 SIXES: ",s_3_q6)
```

This is how to solve the problem, can be values other than 3 and 6 and should still work! Thanks @JohanC

```
INPUT QUADRANT

SCT 3 CHANGE:  33
SCT 6 CHANGE:  36
TIME:  8
SECT 3 THREES:  5.0
SECT 3 SIXES:  3.0
```